# facebook JS SDK: Asynchronous load doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is my code which is throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`. It works fine synchronously if I remove `window.fbAsyncInit` method and add `<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` in `<head>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        function login()
        {
            FB.login
            (
                function( response )
                {
                    if ( response.authResponse )
                    {
                        FB.api
                        (
                            "/me",
                            function( response )
                            {
                                document.getElementById( "profile_name" ).innerHTML = response.name;
                                document.getElementById( "list" ).innerHTML = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/friends";
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        function getFriends() {
            alert('1');
            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
                //alert('2:'+response.data);
                if(response.data) {
                    $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                        //alert(friend.name + ' has id:' + friend.id);
                        $( "list" ).append = response.name;
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Error!");
                }
            });
        }

     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>

        window.fbAsyncInit = function()
        {
            FB.init
            (
                {
                    appId   : "109036532604620",
                    channelUrl:"http://localhost/testsaav/channel.html",
                    status  : true,
                    cookie  : true,
                    oauth   : true
                }
            );

        };

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            alert('connected');
          } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // not_authorized
          } else {
            // not_logged_in
          }
         });

        (function(d, debug){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document, /*debug*/ true));
    </script>    
    <a href="javascript:getFriends();">Login</a>
    <img id="profile_pic"/>
    <pre id="list"></pre>
    <div id="profile_name"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's telling you that `FB` is not defined because, unless you import the Facebook code with a `<script>` tag, it is in fact not defined.  Facebook is not a native browser facility.

Comment: That's what the final function of the code sample does @Pointy

Comment: @TommyBs well sure that's true - I should have said "unless/until you import the Facebook code **somehow** "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert('connected');
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
      }
     });
```

this code after the FB.init function but inside the window.fbAsyncInit function e.g

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
        FB.init
        (
            {
                appId   : "109036532604620",
                channelUrl:"http://localhost/testsaav/channel.html",
                status  : true,
                cookie  : true,
                oauth   : true
            }
        );

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        alert('connected');
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        // not_authorized
      } else {
        // not_logged_in
      }
     });

    };
```

You'll notice from the sample at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ that your initialization code should go after the init method within the asyncinit method to function correctly. This ensures things are called in the correct order once the SDK has been loaded

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/